# How to add Label in R Ploting for Clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I followed this instruction to create a "Fan" phylogenetic trees in R. But I can not get the correct labels.

The command I am trying is:

```
plot(
    as.phylo(hc), 
    type = "fan", 
    tip.color = hsv(runif(15, 0.65, 0.95), 1, 1, 0.7), 
    edge.color = hsv(runif(10, 0.65, 0.75), 1, 1, 0.7), 
    edge.width = runif(20, 0.5, 3), 
    use.edge.length = TRUE, 
    col = "gray80")
```

My goal is:

[image: Instructions]

But my current result is:

[image: My Result]

Comment: Could you include the output of `hc$labels`

Comment: I have a problem with posting a message on Stackoverflow. BTW, it is the instruction code.
plot(as.phylo(hc), type = "fan", tip.color = hsv(runif(15, 0.65, 
    0.95), 1, 1, 0.7), edge.color = hsv(runif(10, 0.65, 0.75), 1, 1, 0.7), edge.width = runif(20, 
    0.5, 3), use.edge.length = TRUE, col = "gray80")

Comment: before trying the above instruction code, can you show us the output of `hc$lables`

Comment: Dear Osssan, when I give the command hc$lables. The returned value is NULL.

Comment: I found someone had the same problem with me. But the code did not work well. It did not show the labels. 
Here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475106/node-labels-on-circular-phylogenetic-tree

Comment: When I tested with another dataset it works. But it did not work with my dataset even the structure are the same.

Comment: Why I can not show the output of hc$label ? Anyone can HELP?